# Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for input. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef(). With React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forms

I am new to react-hook-form.
I am pasting my code below

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Inventory = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        className="border border-gray-900 rounded-lg p-2"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Number"
        ref={register("number", { required: true })}
      />
      {errors.number && <p>This is required</p>}
      <button
        className="mt-4 text-white bg-gray-900 border-2 border-gray-900 rounded-md px-2 py-1"
        type="submit"
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Inventory;
```

When I am submitting the form I am not getting any output in the console. Also I am getting an warning as

`Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for input. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().`

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I made a mistake in the code.
I wrote this

```
 ref={register("number", { required: true })}
```

Instead of this

```
{...register("number", { required: true })}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case i removed `ref` dotn know whether it is the right fix

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you got the error was because `useRef` was not imported in the code.

```
Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for input. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().
```

I had the same error and by using `useRef`, I fixed it.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
```

`ref` is a attribute which comes from `useRef` itself and is usually to do Vanilla JS stuff in React App